# Prove or disprove : IF $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) = 0$ THEN $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{1}{f(x)} = \infty$ or $-\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I was able to prove that IF $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) = \infty$ THEN $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{1}{f(x)} = 0$. In order to prove the following: IF $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) = 0$ then $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{1}{f(x)} = \infty$ or $-\infty$, do I just reverse the argument? Cause that seems too easy and straightforward.

Comment: How about $f(x)=x$?

Comment: Your claim is false : there can be no limit. What is true is that if the limit does exist, then it has to be $+\infty$ or $-\infty$

Answer (score 1):

The statement is false. Take, for instance, $f(x)=x$. Then $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=0$ but the limit $\lim_{x\to0}\frac1{f(x)}$ does not exist.

Comment: are we allowed to pick "a"? I was wondering how do I prove this in general since im not given "a"

Comment: In the general case, you consider $f(x)=x-a$.